# How can I access a photo location tag through the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location

I am developing an application in which I want to collect all the location information the user has provided through either wall posts, checkins or photo uploads.

I have currently found the way to get the location tags attached to posts by accessing the `place` field that each entry of the `feed` connection has. In a similar way I have managed to get the location tags of user's checkins (`place` field of `checkins` connection).

However, I cannot find a way to get the location tags of the `photos` placed into albums. The fields I can access for each photo through the Graph API are: `id`, `from`, `tags`, `name`, `icon`, `picture`, `source`, `height`, `width`, `images`, `link`, `created_time`, `updated_time`, `position`. 
(The `tag` field refers only to users' tagging.)

So, is there a way I can get the location tag of a photo?

Answer (score 1):

I took a photo with my mobile phone and uploaded it to facebook with a place tag.

After that I looked on my feed data with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and see the photo with the place.

I think the easiest way is to load the feed data and search for "places" in it.

Comment: Thank you but this only works when posting a photo on the wall, and a mobile photo upload does exactly that. My question is how I can get location information about photos placed inside albums, which have not necessarily been published in the user's wall, so they cannot be found in the feed.